# Create variable with multiple lines of html in php

Tags: php, function, variables, subroutine

In perl I can qq[] to put multiple lines of html into a variable as shown below.

**PERL**

```
my $rank = 1;
my $name = 'John';

sub writeMsg
{
    $test = qq[
        <h1>User Ranking</h1>
        <p>$name is ranked number $rank</p>
        <p>lots more info to go in here</p>
    ];

    return $test;
}

print writeMsg($rank, $name);
```

In php I can't seem to find a way to do this?
The soloution I have below returns the same result but it is already a lot harder to read and keep the syntax right,

**PHP**

```
$rank=1;
$name = 'John';
function writeMsg($rank, $name) {     
        $test = '<h1>User Ranking</h1>' . $name . ' is ranked number ' . $rank ' <p>lots more info to go in here</p>';
    return $test;
}

print writeMsg($rank, $name);
```

Is there a way to do this in php?  I am familiar with doing something similar in a foreach with the below syntax but haven't been able to come up with a good way to do this for a variable?

```
    <?php foreach ($get_tests as $test): ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use `"` instead of `'`

```
$test= "
    <h1>User Ranking</h1>
    <p>$name is ranked number $rank</p>
    <p>lots more info to go in here</p>
";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the heredoc (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
<?php
$str = <<<"EOD"
<p>Example of string</p>
<b>spanning multiple lines</b>
<p>using nowdoc syntax.</p>
EOD;

echo $str;
```

Edit: make sure to use double quotes

Comment: see the edit - double quotes are needed around "EOD"

Comment: Thanks @Dave Chen heredoc is the way to go not the nowdoc. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc